# How can a web site display a new font?

Tags: fonts

Is there any way a web site can download and install a new font on a client's computer?  Or is there any other way to cause a new font to be displayed on a client's computer?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=web+fonts

Comment: It is difficult to ask users to install a font. Maybe you can use Google Fonts http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 1):

Honest answer: No. At least not in a reasonable way.

If you want static text to be displayed in another font, just create an image on your developement maschien and display that instead of the text.

You could use transparency so, you don't have to recreate the image should your pages background change.

Comment: An image won't work.  I want to set the font for all paragraphs or all H2s, etc.

Answer (score 0):

WebFonts can help you http://www.google.com/webfonts.
You can find documentation on https://developers.google.com/webfonts/?hl=fr

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the font style according to the user agents you can use CSS "font-family" property as below,

put your font choices in order of your preference. I mean, if the browser doesn't have the first family on the list, it will try the second and then the third and so on until it finds one it has on the system.

font-family: font1, font2, font3;

In the above example, the browser will first check for the "font1" font, then "font2" and finally if neither of those were found, it will check for "font3".

Comment: I'm asking the question because I noticed one site builder offering 130 fonts to choose from - things like "Aller", "Amaranth", "Cantarell", "Dosis", "Droid Sans" "Folks Lignt", "Inconsolata" -  for paragraph style, paragraph heading style, etc., and they show a pretty picture of each font.  But my Windows 7 Pro system has maybe 2% of those fonts.  So it's not really honest to make a site builder think that by selecting one of those fonts their site visitors will see it - unless I'm missing something and there really is away to download the fonts with the page.

Comment: Ok, I've read up and know a bit more now.  The solution is to use CSS3's @font-face.  (Google fonts work also, but people say they're "awful.")  Additionally using the WOFF format of the font gets you a compressed version that loads faster.